# @BasePathAwareController Exception: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

```java
@BasePathAwareController
public class MetricController {

    @Autowired
    private MetricRepository metricRepository;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/metrics/in/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody
    MetricDTO getMetric(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return MetricDTO.fromEntity(metricRepository.getOne(id));
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"metricType", "instanceType"}, name = "customUniqueId")
)
public class Metric implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private SourceType sourceType;
    private String metricTypeField;
    private String metricType;
    private String instanceType;
    private String instanceTypeField;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> metricIdFields;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> valueFields;
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, String> virtualFieldValueEx;
}

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MetricDTO {
    private SourceType sourceType;
    private String metricTypeField;
    private String metricType;
    private String instanceType;
    private String instanceTypeField;
    private List<String> metricIdFields;
    private List<String> valueFields;
    private Map<String, String> virtualFieldValueEx;

    public static MetricDTO fromEntity(Metric metric) {
        return new MetricDTO(
                metric.getSourceType(),
                metric.getMetricTypeField(),
                metric.getMetricType(),
                metric.getInstanceType(),
                metric.getInstanceTypeField(),
                metric.getMetricIdFields(),
                metric.getValueFields(),
                metric.getVirtualFieldValueEx()
        );
    }
}
```

Since @RepositoryRestController in Spring Data Rest is not compatible with Swagger, I changed it to @BasePathAwareController.

So, the problem is that the controller is not working properly.

The error history is as follows.

```java
Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.jmsight.management.entity.Metric.metricIdFields, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.jmsight.management.entity.Metric.metricIdFields, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.jmsight.management.dto.MetricDTO[&quot;metricIdFields&quot;])
```

Using @RepositoryRestController works normally.
What is the problem? Is it resolvable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source of `@BasePathAwareController` then you can see that it's **not** annotated with `@Controller`.
So if a class is annotated only with `@BasePathAwareController` then it won't be picked neither by the default SpringMvc neither RepositoryRestMvc.

The former picks classes annotated with `@Controller` **or** `@RequestMapping`, the latter picks only classes annotated with `@RepositoryRestController`.

So once again, just to make it clear: `@BasePathAwareController` is **NOT** an 'extension' of `@Controller`, it's just a additional 'sign' annotation.
You can use `@Controller` together with `@BasePathAwareController` instead of `@RequestMapping` too.

I believe it's a misleading naming, or simply a bug in the implementation.

One more thing.
If you switch the from `@RepositoryRestController` to `@Controller`/`@RequestMapping`, then your controller will be handled a completely different way.
It could look that it works the same way, but it's called by a completely different handlerMapping: which uses different converters, argumentResolvers, even a different objectMapper.

There could be unpleasant surprises if you need to implement more complicated handler-methods in your controller-class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

To share, @BasePathAwareController should be written in class as @RequestMapping.

I don't know why. If you know reason teach me please.

```java
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping(value = "your url value")
public class MetricController {}
```